# How to parse data inside a string?

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have data like this:

```
    '[        {            
     "agent_id": 558921,        
     "agent_name": "The City Townhouse",        
     "attributes": {               
     "agent_ratings_enabled": 0,             
     "approved": 1,                          
     "attribute_set_id": 1,  
     "categories": JSON.parse("[15,19]"),          
     "indoor_features": ["Balcony","Maid\\\'s room"],        
     "is_agent": 1}    ];'
```

And I dont have any idea how parse them. Its just a part of a string.

My code is here:

```
import requests
import re

res = requests.get('https://www.lamudi.com.ph/brandnew-modern-duplex-2-car-garage-house-and-lot-for-sale-in-betterliving-md.html')
res = res.content 
RE_OFFER_DATA_JSON_FROM_FLAT_PAGE = r".dataLayer = (.+?)<\/script>"
OFFER_DATA_JSON = re.compile(RE_OFFER_DATA_JSON_FROM_FLAT_PAGE) 
data = OFFER_DATA_JSON.search(str(res)).group(1) 
text = data.replace("\\n", "") 
print(text)
```

I know, that it's not good idea to use regex, but I don't have another way.

Thanks for any advise

Comment: Looks ike it might be JSON, except for the ; at the end. Try `value = json.loads(res)` or better don’t overwrite res with res.content and just use `value=res.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load the JSON data from this site, it needs to be cleaned from Javascript first:

```
import re
import json
import requests

res = requests.get(
    "https://www.lamudi.com.ph/brandnew-modern-duplex-2-car-garage-house-and-lot-for-sale-in-betterliving-md.html"
)

data = re.search(r"dataLayer = (\[.*?\]);", res.text, flags=re.S).group(1)

# clean the data from Javascript artifacts:
data = re.sub(r'JSON.parse\("(.*?)"\)', r"\1", data)
data = re.sub(r",\s*}", r"}", data)
data = re.sub(r"navigator\.userAgent", r'""', data)

# parse the data
data = json.loads(data)

# pretty print the data:
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
[
    {
        "agent_id": 558921,
        "agent_name": "The City Townhouse",
        "attributes": {
            "agent_ratings_enabled": 0,
            "approved": 1,
            "attribute_set_id": 1,
            "categories": [
                15,
                19
            ],
            "indoor_features": [
                "Balcony",
                "Maid's room"
            ],
            "is_agent": 1,
            "listing_type": "Classifieds",
            "other_features": [],
            "outdoor_features": [
                "Garage"
            ],
            "price_formatted": "\u20b1 11,300,000 ",
            "price_not_shown": false,
            "seller_is_trusted": 1,
            "show_listing_address": 1,
            "show_mobile": 1,
            "is_whatsapp": 1,
            "is_viber": 0,
            "is_facebook": 0,
            "show_officephone": 0,
            "top_position": 0,
            "urlkey_details": "brandnew-modern-duplex-2-car-garage-house-and-lot-for-sale-in-betterliving-md.html",
            "bathrooms": 3,
            "bedrooms": 3,
            "building_size": 210,
            "car_spaces": 2,
            "land_size": 150,
            "agency_name": "The City Townhouse",
            "alternate_sku": "39131996",
            "attribute_set_name": "House",
            "currency_code": "PHP",
            "listing_start": "2021-02-09 11:26:05",
            "name": "Brandnew Modern Duplex 2 Car Garage House and Lot for Sale in Betterliving-MD",
            "price": 11300000,
            "product_owner": 558921,
            "product_owner_name": "The City Townhouse",
            "product_owner_url_key": "miyabi-realty-agn-8",
            "root_category": 15,
            "sku": "HO602200CD8819DPH",
            "status": "active",
            "status_supplier_config": "active",
            "subcategory": "Townhouse",
            "subcategory_id": 19,
            "offer_type_id": 2,
            "location_latitude": "14.482705",
            "location_longitude": "121.024909",
            "listing_region": "Metro Manila",
            "offer_type": "Buy",
            "listing_area": "Don Bosco",
            "listing_city": "Para\u00f1aque",
            "image_url": "https://static-ph.lamudi.com/static/media/bm9uZS9ub25l/2x2x5x880x396/ac7e9e4327f459.jpg"
        },
        "country": "ph",
        "description": {
            "characters": 438,
            "text": "Duplex 2 Storey Townhouse3 Bedrooms3 Toilet &amp;amp; BathMaids RoomLiving RoomDinning RoomKitchen AreaBalconyMaster Bedrooms w/ walk in closetSELLING PRICE:11.3MLot Area:150 sqmFloor Area:210sqmTerms Of Payment:400K Reservation20% Downpayment80% Bank Finance",
            "words": 31
        },
        "device_agent": "",
        "device_type": "desktop",
        "images": 15,
        "language": "en",
        "location": {
            "area": "Don Bosco",
            "city": "Para\u00f1aque",
            "region": "Metro Manila"
        },
        "login_state": false,
        "number_of_product_attributes": 49,
        "number_of_product_features": 3,
        "sku": "HO602200CD8819DPH",
        "title": "Brandnew Modern Duplex 2 Car Garage House and Lot for Sale in Betterliving-MD",
        "page_type": "product"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's valid JSON you can use json built-in module, in particular the `json.loads()` function which parses strings.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html